# Some questions about using NLog

Tags: c#, nlog

I installed Nlog and configured it followingly

```
    public static Logger _logger = null;

    static void foo()
    { 
        var config = new LoggingConfiguration();

        var fileTarget = new FileTarget();
        config.AddTarget("file", fileTarget);

        // Step 3. Set target properties 
        fileTarget.Layout = @"${date:format=HH\:mm\:ss} - ${message}"; 
        fileTarget.FileName = "c:/myFolder/" + "${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.log";

        var rule2 = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, fileTarget);
        config.LoggingRules.Add(rule2);

        // Step 5. Activate the configuration
        LogManager.Configuration = config;

        // Example usage
        _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Example");
        _logger.Error("error log message");

    }
```

But I would like to ask some questions.

1. I am going to use NLog from a DLL. If many different programs use my DLL, is writing to log files still safe? Will there be no races when different programs try to write to same log file via NLog?
2. Is it ok to use a single static variable of Logger type throughout whole DLL?
3. Is it possible to use NLog in my DLL such that apps that use DLL can configure to output to different log files for example? How to achieve that? In other words as I said my DLL is using NLog. Say my DLL has method `foo` which uses NLog to write to log file. Now when someone wants to use my DLL they can specify in which folder NLog should write. Now when some other program starts to use my DLL, I want them to be able to also specify a different folder to write to. Do you see? So program A writes to folder C: using my DLL but program B write to folder D: using my DLL also at the same time.

Comment: `fileTarget.FileName = "c:/myFolder/${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.log"` for first question. And could you explain more about your 2en question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [Refer to Nlog's documentations](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target#performance-tuning-options) multiple process could write to same file and Nlog could handle that. Also you could control it by `concurrentWrites` property.
2. As far as I understand from code Nlog tries best to return same instance of logger when you call `LogManager.GetLogger()` method.
3. If you want to have separate log file per process simply use variables on `FileName`

   `fileTarget.FileName = "c:/myFolder/${processid}/${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.log"`

   or

   `fileTarget.FileName = "c:/myFolder/${processname}/${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.log"`

But if you want your users could change log path you could save the path in a app relative file and set it to `fileTarget.FileName` every time you need it.

```
// imagine this method returns "c:/myPath"
string logFolderPath = AskPathFromUser();

// since your logPath.txt file is app relative. 
// each process will have own file next to process file. 
File.WriteAllText("logPath.txt", logFolderPath);

// now every time you need to set the path read the saved path from file
fileTarget.FileName=Path.Combine(File.ReadAllText("logPath.txt"),"${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.log");
```

Comment: I have updated my question, if you can adapt your answer to my updated question that would be nice.

Comment: Also users typically specify path not like c:/myFolder but like c:\\somefolder\\otherfolder etc. - different slashes. How to handle this?

Comment: See my updated post. You could use `string.Replace()` method then.

Comment: I think I will need a separate question for that but what I mean is. I said my DLL is using NLog. Say my DLL has method foo which uses NLog to write to log file. Now when someone wants to use my DLL they can specify in which folder NLog should write. Now when some other program starts to use my DLL, I want them to be able to also specify a different folder to write to. Do you see? So program A writes to folder C: using my DLL but program B write to folder D: using my DLL also at the same time.

Comment: Ok thats not what I meant but I will accept it because I want one user to write to one log other user to other log